# Set locale in ng2-pagination

Tags: angular, pagination, localization

I am trying to set the locale in my project. So far I have used i18n for HTML plain text, but I do not know how to set the locale for ng2-pagination?

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved by providing the label for Previous and Next with the values of their translations. The appropriate translation is picked up by angular during bootstrap